# How do I use xpage 'JDBC Connection Manager' Extension Control

Tags: jdbc, xpages

I have Domino 8.5.3 with the newest OpenNTF Extension Library, and I can't quite seem to find a clear explanation for when to use the xpage 'JDBC Connection Manager' Extension Control.  In the XpagesJDBC.nsf examples, I see it used on a couple different xpages, but I'm not sure how you determine if you use the Control, or just refer to your connection directly in your Data Source tab.  I must be missing something.  Can anyone help me understand?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

JDBC Connection manager is used primarily for two reasons. It allows you to batch multiple calls into a single transaction. This helps to reduce the additional overhead that is incurred by having multiple calls for multiple transactions. By default the connection manager's auto commit is set to false, which allows you then to batch each call.

Using the connection manager also allows you to set a transactional isolation level to alleviate issues with concurrency to maintain data integrity. Concurrency issues such as dirty reads, unrepeatable reads, and phantom reads can occur in multi-user multi-threaded applications where the same dataset can be affected in different ways at different times.

Read up on Concurrency and Transactional Isolation on the web to get more info on all that...

But bottom line, if you have multiple RDMS data sources on your XPage, or if you are executing multiple transaction in a single XPage "rendering" then consider using the Connection Manager, otherwise you can directly use the jdbcRowSet or jdbcQuery data sources directly.

Hope that helps!